# How to get access to specific layer using tensorflow estimator and dataset API?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow 1.3.0 to train a CNN classification model. However I need to get access to the prelogits layer to evaluate my method (i.e. while this is casted as a classification problem, the method is not a classification problem but is used to extract CNN features, i.e. to produce a point in an N-dimensional vector space for an input image test)

I am using both the dataset API (with TFRecord files) and the estimator API to train the model. However, I don't see how I can get access/return the prelogits value using the Estimator API, i.e. `estimator.train()`, `.evaluate()` or `.predict()` since `model_fn()` needs to return a specific `tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec` object.

Previously (i.e. using the standard `sess=tf.Session()` method) I could train the model and get access to the prelogits layer while training (or by loading the model after training) and feed the network with a specific input to get the specific layer output with a `sess.run(specific_layer)` as long as the layer was named `specific_layer`.

I have tried to use the prediction output of `EstimatorSpec` but it did not work. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you can actually use the `predictions` argument of `EstimatorSpec` to get access to a feature layer, although it is not really what it is meant to be for...